Multi Vendor Module for Magento 2 gives an error
Unable to apply data patch Webkul\Marketplace\Setup\Patch\Data\InsertDefaultData for module Webkul_Marketplace. Original exception message: Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Controllers\Collection\Interceptor::$storeManager is deprecated in /home/1276058.cloudwaysapps.com/rtcgeaddsr/public_html/app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractCollection.php on line 46

I have the same issue. Can someone please tell how to solve this step by step? It seems that this module is not compatible with PHP 8.2 But Magento 2.4.7 requires PHP 8.2 Anyone has the solution?

Open file
Webkul/Marketplace/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractCollection.php
Here you need not to define the variable directly you can create the object in controller,
you need to define that varibale.
Thank You!
